# Efficient mean and standard deviation calculation using a lot of similar structured files in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple question about mean calculation in a dataframe where all the data was split into a lot of small files..
The structure of such files is similar - it's the data of >1000 experiments for the same conditions but the data has some uncertainty which has to be estimated statistically.

each file has such structure:

```
local_coordinate | param1_val | param2_val | param3_val ...
```

Where local_coordinate is actually is the grid almost the same for all  files..
Each file has about 10000 rows and about 20 columns.

Each row of each experimental datafile corresponds for the local_coordinate value - the sets of local_coordinate values are the same for all the files.

E.g. the data in one experiment .csv  file:

```
12.77 | 24.53 | 2 | 21 ...
12.79 | 24.53 | 2 | 21 ...
12.84 | 24.53 | 2 | 21 ...
12.85 | 24.53 | 2 | 21 ...
```

For other file data in one experiment .csv  file:

```
12.77 | 24.59 | 2 | 21 ...
12.79 | 24.56 | 2 | 22 ...
12.84 | 24.52 | 2 | 20 ...
12.85 | 24.54 | 2 | 21 ...
```

1. How to calculate the distributions for unique values of local_coordinates?

Maybe there is a way to do this in efficient way using pandas? without constructing one large dataset and making a lot of subsets?

2. It would be much better if we can use intervals for calculation (it can be more convenient for analysis) - for example we need to calculate mean and SD of parameters :

val-threshold <= local_coordinate <= val+threshold

In mentioned example if threshold == 0, and local_coordinate = 12.77 the output will be
param1_val_mean = (Sum of all values of param1_val where local_coordinate = 12.77) / (Number of rows in all files where local_coordinate = 12.77)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it seems that there is no "correct" answer on this question..

I have collected one big dataframe and worked with the subqueries to process the data .. But of course that approach isn't fast enough..